# Slider com uma única imagem animando

Tags: jquery, css3, slider, horizontal

Gostaria de criar um *slideshow* [nesse estilo](http://www.visioncritical.com/evolution-of-insight/), com uma imagem única que se move horizontalmente com a navegação. Alguém me sugere um plugin nesse estilo?

Criei aqui um esboço do que eu quero: https://jsfiddle.net/camilam/rLnsxwt4/
Só que como estou iniciando em jquery, meus códigos estão meio na gambiarra, queria saber se há uma técnica melhor de se fazer isso.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".box01").hide();
 $(".irparaslide02").click(function() {
  $('#imagem').addClass('move01para02');
  $("#proximo").removeClass('irparaslide02').addClass('irparaslide03');
  $("#anterior").addClass('move02para01');

  $(".irparaslide03").click(function() {
   $('#imagem').removeClass('move01para02').addClass('move02para03');
   $("#proximo").removeClass('irparaslide03').addClass('irparaslide04');
   $(".box01").show(slow);
   
  });
 });
});
```

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}
#infografico{width:100%;overflow:hidden;position:relative}
nav{position: absolute;top: 50%;width: 100%;}
nav #anterior{position:absolute; top:50%; left:5%; background-color:#fff}
nav #proximo{position:absolute; top:50%; right:5%; background-color:#fff}
#imagem{background:url(http://kgbm.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/sydney1a-wide.jpg) 0px 0px no-repeat; width:2000px; height:400px}
.move01para02{animation-name:move01para02;animation-duration:1s;animation-timing-function:ease-in, ease-in-out;animation-fill-mode:forwards;}
@keyframes move01para02{
0% {background-position: 0px}
100%{ background-position: -200px}
}
.move02para01{animation-name:move02para01;animation-duration:1s;animation-timing-function:ease-in, ease-in-out;animation-fill-mode:forwards;}
@keyframes move02para01{
0% {background-position: -200px}
100%{ background-position: 0px}
}
.show{width:30px; height:30px; background-color:#000}
.move02para03{animation-name:move02para03;animation-duration:1s;animation-timing-function:ease-in, ease-in-out;animation-fill-mode:forwards;}
@keyframes move02para03{
0% {background-position: -200px}
100%{ background-position: -400px}
}
.show{width:30px; height:30px; background-color:#000}
.box01{background:#fff;color:#000; position:absolute; top:20px; left:200px}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<div id="infografico">
<nav><li><a href="#" id="anterior" class="">voltar</a></li><li><a href="#" id="proximo" class="irparaslide02">ir</a></li></nav>
<div id="imagem"></div>
<div class="box01">box de texto 01</div>
```

Comment: O que vc já tem de código HTML/CSS/JS? Tem uma imagem do layout de como vc quer que fique? Coloque mais detalhes e os código que fica mais fácil de te responder.

Comment: O carrossel do Jquery não resolve?

Comment: O site não funciona desta forma, sua pergunta é muito ampla, você deve postar perguntas informando o problema que você teve ao tentar fazer um slide deste tipo, você deve ser mais especifica mostrando o que fez você não conseguir continuar.

Comment: Você pode procurar um código JS, Jquery ou HTML5 e criar um. Pode de adaptar ao que você precisa. Ter a imagem de fundo e dividir em 3 ou mais e usar as imagens na ordem para produzir o slide ao fundo.

Comment: inseri mais informações e um esboço do que eu to tentando fazer...

Comment: Camila recomendo que vc estude sobre Parallax (pesquise no Google), tem muita coisa que da para fazer com CSS antes de precisar usar JS ou jQuery.